# I don't know how to reduce nesting code in c#

Tags: c#

```
private void MoveFooders()
{
    if (Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0)
    {
        bool fnd = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < world.food.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) < 0.2f && Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) < 0.2f)
            {
                fnd = true;
                isFood = 3.0f;

                world.food[i].n -= 3.0f;

                if (world.food[i].n < 0)
                {
                    world.food.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (fnd == false)
        {
            isDest = false;
            antType = scouts;
        }
    }
  
    else if (Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0)
    {
        antbase.food += isFood;
        isFood = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither is Math.Abs. C#? Wrong tag?

Comment: Yes, i confuse, it c#

Comment: You can always [edit] your question. But please take some time to take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't understand how to reduce code nesting

Comment: Do you really think the code is now more readable since your edit? BTW It is very obvious that you are talking about c# code because you already tagged the question with **c#**

Answer (score 0):

When looking at reducing nesting a first step would be to look at code that is only run under certain conditions and see if it is possible to reorder code in a more readable manner i.e. so that you don't have to scan over a lot of code just to see what is being run if the statement isn't true, that may also exit those sections of code more quickly.

You have a couple of `if` statements that you could invert and that would reduce nesting e.g.,

```
    private void MoveFooders()
    {
        if (Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0)
        {
            bool fnd = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < world.food.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!(Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) < 0.2f) || !(Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) < 0.2f)) continue;
                fnd = true;
                isFood = 3.0f;

                world.food[i].n -= 3.0f;

                if (world.food[i].n < 0)
                {
                    world.food.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                break;
            }

            if (fnd != false) return;
            isDest = false;
            antType = scouts;
        }

        else if (Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0)
        {
            antbase.food += isFood;
            isFood = 0.0f;
        }
    }
```

Next look at some of your condition statements and see if there is logic that overrides function e.g.:

`if (Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0)`

I see that when

`isFood == 0` is `false`

you'll skip to

`else if (Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0)`

where

`isFood != 0` will always be true, so that check could be removed.

However, just as an aside I see that you're setting `isFood` to `0.0f` so I assume that `isFood` is declared as a float type thus checks against `0` will likely fail as a float type is rarely, if ever, exactly `0` instead you'll need to use something like `Math.Abs(isFood)<0.00001` instead of `isFood==0`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it iteratively, and also use some local variables.

Since we cannot just switch the order of the if-then-else main block, because you have else-if, we just use some local variables.

Step 1:

```
private void MoveFooders()
{
    bool state1 = Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0;
    bool state2 = Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0;

    if (!state1 && state2)
    {
        antbase.food += isFood;
        isFood = 0.0f;
        return;
    }
    
    if (!state1)
        return;
        
    bool fnd = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < world.food.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) < 0.2f && Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) < 0.2f)
        {
            fnd = true;
            isFood = 3.0f;

            world.food[i].n -= 3.0f;

            if (world.food[i].n < 0)
            {
                world.food.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fnd == false)
    {
        isDest = false;
        antType = scouts;
    }
}
```

*(you will have to come up with good names for the two state variables since you know best what kind of scenarios they detect)*

Then, let's do something similar to the if-statement inside the loop, by inverting the expression and using continue to skip the rest of the loop body. Then we can remove one level of nesting from that as well:

```
private void MoveFooders()
{
    bool state1 = Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0;
    bool state2 = Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0;

    if (!state1 && state2)
    {
        antbase.food += isFood;
        isFood = 0.0f;
        return;
    }
    
    if (!state1)
        return;
        
    bool fnd = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < world.food.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!(Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) < 0.2f && Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) < 0.2f))
            continue;

        fnd = true;
        isFood = 3.0f;

        world.food[i].n -= 3.0f;

        if (world.food[i].n < 0)
        {
            world.food.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        break;
    }

    if (fnd == false)
    {
        isDest = false;
        antType = scouts;
    }
}
```

I would then reverse the expression in the inner if-statement, from this:

```
if (!(Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) < 0.2f && Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) < 0.2f))
```

to this:

```
if (Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) >= 0.2f || Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) >= 0.2f)
```

Last bit would be to reverse the last if-statement, if that makes more logical sense but this wouldn't be a priority for me at least.

From this:

```
if (fnd == false)
{
    isDest = false;
    antType = scouts;
}
```

to this:

```
if (fnd)
    return;

isDest = false;
antType = scouts;
```

You could also argue that since the loop breaks when it has found something, and the next step is then just to return, you don't need the `fnd` variable and can instead return from inside the loop. This means the final step could be this:

```
private void MoveFooders()
{
    bool state1 = Math.Abs(destPointX - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(destPointY - y) < 0.2 && isFood == 0;
    bool state2 = Math.Abs(200 - x) < 0.2 && Math.Abs(200 - y) < 0.2 && isFood != 0;

    if (!state1 && state2)
    {
        antbase.food += isFood;
        isFood = 0.0f;
        return;
    }
    
    if (!state1)
        return;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < world.food.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(world.food[i].x - x) >= 0.2f || Math.Abs(world.food[i].y - y) >= 0.2f)
            continue;

        isFood = 3.0f;

        world.food[i].n -= 3.0f;

        if (world.food[i].n < 0)
        {
            world.food.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        return;
    }

    isDest = false;
    antType = scouts;
}
```